# How should I create a files just for functions?

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

I am making a BST class and I want to put the traversal functions (inorer, preorder, postorder, levelscan) in a separate file. I am unsure how to go on about this though. I tried making an .h file but it did not work. Since it's not really a class definition, should I still make a Traversal class? or just go straight for the function definitions?

```
#ifndef TREETRAV_H
#define TREETRAV_H

#include "TreeNode.h"
#include <iostream.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

template <class T>
class TreeTrav
{
friend class BinSTree<T>;
public:
void PreOrderVisit(TreeNode *t, void visit(T& item));
void InOrderVisit(TreeNode *t, void visit(T& item));
void PostOrderVisit(TreeNode *t, void visit(T& item));
void LevelScan(TreeNode *t, void visit(T& item));

};
#endif
```

Comment: What you are showing looks fine for `treenav.h`. You would then put the function definitions for `PreOrderVisit, etc..` in `treenav.cpp` and at the top of `treenav.cpp` include the line `#include "treenav.h"`. In whatever program file contains `main()` you would likewise include the line `#include "treenav.h"`. You should then be able to compile with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -o progname progname.cpp treenav.cpp` and be fine. You will have to include the file in whatever relies on the template definition.

Answer (score 1):

Since `TreeTrav` is a class template, you cannot implement this class in a separate CPP file. This wont work. Templates follow 2-phase compilation process. First phase would check the basic syntax (like correct for loop usage, proper brackets etc). Second phase would actually compile it against the template type. Therefore, .CPP file will only have first phase of compilation, and later you'll get linker errors (For example `TreeTrav<int>::foo` is not defined).

It would be better to implement all of class (template) in header file only. Or you may have to put `#include<cpp-file-name>` at the end of this header file.